# Right statistical test for my problem

Tags: statistical-significance, dataset

I have a bunch of data like these:

```
       Out1     Out2    Out3    Out4    Out5    Out6                 
x1     0.76     0.57    0.45    0.38    0.32    0.28
x2     0.79     0.59    0.47    0.39    0.34    0.29
x3     0.81     0.61    0.49    0.41    0.35    0.31
x4     0.84     0.63    0.51    0.42    0.36    0.32
x5     0.87     0.65    0.52    0.44    0.37    0.33
x6     0.90     0.68    0.54    0.45    0.39    0.34
x7     0.93     0.70    0.56    0.47    0.40    0.35
x8     0.96     0.72    0.58    0.48    0.41    0.36
x9     0.99     0.74    0.59    0.49    0.42    0.37
x10    1.02     0.76    0.61    0.51    0.44    0.38
x11    1.05     0.79    0.63    0.52    0.45    0.39
```

There is a significant decrease from `out1` to `out2` columns. Between the columns, only the numbers in same row should be compared. For example, I should NOT compare `[x1 out1]` with `[x2 out2]`. I should only compare `[x1 out1]` with `[x1 out2]`

I'd like to know how I can statistically show that at a specific column (e.g. column `out10`) this significant decrease stops (there is no significant different between the results of the column `out10` to `out11`).

I appreciate any help.

ADDED: An example of the application:
Assume that you have several linear springs with soft to stiff materials. `Out_i` in the above table is related to the materials from soft (`out1`) to stiff (`out6`). The `x_i` parameters are the amount of displacement of the springs from low (`x1`) to high (`x11`). The values of the tables are the forces required to produce `x_i` amount of displacement in the spring with `out_i` material. I'd like to show that the is no significant decrease in the forces in a specific material (this means that there is no need to make it any softer!)

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Can you explain the application or give an example in which these data arise? I believe you may be interested in a change point analysis in time series... but titles like "out" and "x" aren't very helpful for variable names.

Comment: Thanks for your welcome! I just updated my question with an example.

Answer (score -1):

I would say, you need a  [paired t-test](http://www.biostathandbook.com/pairedttest.html)

In R it would be

```
t.test(data[,'Out5'], data[,'Out6'], paired=TRUE)
```

The output will give you the probability of the null hypothesis: the mean difference between paired observations is zero. Large probability means "significant decrease stoped".

t-test assumes that differences between pairs are normally distributed. As alternative you can consider rank-based [matched-pairs Wilcoxon test](http://www.biostathandbook.com/wilcoxonsignedrank.html). In R it would be

```
wilcox.test(data[,'Out5'], data[,'Out6'], paired=TRUE)
```

ADDED  If you to go for statistical test, then, yes, you need to repeat it between all *consecutive* columns (5 and 6, 6 an 7, 7 and 8).

If you want it with more intuition you can visualize your differences. Produce "relative decrease" columns like `(Out5-Out6)/Out5` for each consecutive pair. Plot the histogram of each with different color. Observe (hopefully) how the peak is moving to zero as you go from (5,6) to (6,7) then (7,8) and so on pairs

Comment: Thanks for your response. Does this mean that I must repeat this between all of the columns?

Comment: @lanenok the t-test does not assume that the data are normally distributed. As an asymptotic test, it is highly powerful and consistent regardless of the data generating mechanism. You should explore simulation studies to compare the relative power of these two tests before making such recommendations!

Comment: @AdamO  I did not write "data are normally distributed", I write "_differences_ between pairs". Here is the [reference](http://www.biostathandbook.com/pairedttest.html), read the "Assumptions" section.  Here is [another reference](http://www.statsdirect.com/help/default.htm#parametric_methods/paired_t.htm). I am glad, however, that you at least explained your downvote

Comment: @ NESHOM When you write "statistically show", I assume that you need some statistical test. I extended my answer to answer your comment.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It doesn't make much sense to just compare the individual close columns without capturing the overall trend of the whole data-set. Please let me know if I am missing something here. Is there any way (statistically or not-statistically) to find the column at which the decrease is not significant, considering all of the data and not just between the two?

Comment: Please define "decrease is not significant".  The difference between you consecutive columns is decreasing with the column number. It means that the probability of null-hypothesis (decrease is zero) will be increasing. This is how the overall trend is captured. Only you can decide at what percent this probability is large enough. This will be your "stop" column.